# DHT in jpeg FILE

Tags: jpeg

I am working on jpeg segments and i came across DHT and i am unable to understand the relation between some hex values shown below starting with 0002 and ending with 607.

FFC4 Huffman tables
001B(length)
0(Huffman table for DC numbers)
1(destination identifier for colour component)

00020301010100000000000000000000( the number of Huffman codewords of length from 1bit through 16 bits are stored in next 16 bytes)
0304010205000607

Thanks,
Y.Anish